# opening modalpopup with gridview delete

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to open a modal popup window when user clicks on the delete image button. when I click on the delete image button, I want the user to go to `grdShoppingCart_RowDeleting` when **Ok** is clicked. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my gridview code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                
            <asp:GridView ID="grdShoppingCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="ui-responsive table-stroke ss-table ui-search-result-table" DataKeyNames="CartID" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="5"  GridLines="None"  OnRowDataBound="grdShoppingCart_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdShoppingCart_RowDeleting"  >
                <Columns>
                    
                    
                     <!-- other clumns here-->
                    
                     <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ControlStyle-CssClass="ss-row" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:ImageButton  ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete1.png"     ToolTip="Click To Delete" AlternateText="Click To delete"   CommandName="Delete"/>                            
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUp" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup">
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlDragPopUp" runat="server" Style="cursor: move;background-color:#DDDDDD;border:solid 1px Gray;color:Black">
                                    <div>
                                       <p>Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
                                    </div>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                   <div>
                                       <p style="text-align: center;">
                                            <asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        
                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
                                                TargetControlID="imgbtnDelete"
                                                PopupControlID="pnlPopUp"
                                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                                CancelControlID="CancelButton"
                                                DropShadow="true"
                                                PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlDragPopUp" />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
           </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
   protected void grdShoppingCart_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int cartId = (int)grdShoppingCart.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["CartID"];
            ShoppingCartData scd = new ShoppingCartData();
            scd.DeleteShoppingCartData(cartId);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the changes that I did to fix the code. I passed the CartID to the code behind

```
 <div >
                                            <p style="display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:space-between;width:220px;">
                                                <asp:Button   ID="OkButton" runat="server"  Text="Remove"  CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CartID") %>'/> &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton"  runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
```

and these are the changes I did in code behind:

```
protected void grdShoppingCart_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

            // Get current grid view row
            GridViewRow row = grdShoppingCart.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            // Get command argument from button, also you could use another approach to get parameters
            Button btn = (Button)row.FindControl("OkButton");

            int cartId = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);

            label1.Text = "The row is going to be deleted: " + cartId;
        }
```

that did the trick.